# A tagging quandary: What to do with [max], [min], and [index]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

So, a common MATLAB question users have is how to find the minimum and/or maximum value in an array and the index of that value. Even though questions like these have been asked a few times, it's hard for users to find them since the titles are usually less than descriptive and the tags are often just `[matlab]`.

So, I decided to start going through and cleaning up some of these questions to make them more likely to be found in searches by newer users. However, I ran into some ambiguity regarding the tagging:

- "max" variations:

  - `[max]` **x 166**
  - `[maximum]` **x 79**
  - `[maxima]` **x 10**
  - `[maxvalue]` **x 7**
- "min" variations:

  - `[minimum]` **x 34**
  - `[min]` **x 23**
- "index" variations:

  - `[indexing]` **x 1052**
  - `[index]` **x 499**
  - `[indexes]` **x 68**
  - `[indices]` **x 5**
  - `[array-indexing]` **x 1**

I think there is definitely a need for some synonymizing to reduce this clutter, but what do people think is the best tag to go with in these situations?

Comment: `indexing` and `index` could have different meanings.

Comment: @Peter: True, I thought that as well. Maybe the "verbs" (`[indexing]`) and the "nouns" (`[index]`) should be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 3):

- `[max]`, `[maxima]` --> `[maximum]`
- `[maxvalue]` needs hand-sorting into `[maximum]`, but `[maxvalue]` I think should stay
- `[min]` --> `[minimum]`

If we want to eliminate `[array-indexing]`:

- `[array-indexing]` --> `[indexing]` + `[arrays]`
- Array-related `[indices]` questions --> `[indexing]` + `[arrays]`
- `[index]`, `[indexes]`, `[indices]` --> `[indexing]`

If we don't:

- `[index]` + `[arrays]` (25) and `[indexing]` + `[arrays]` (24) --> `[array-indexing]`
- Array-related `[indices]` questions --> `[array-indexing]`
- `[index]`, `[indexes]`, `[indices]` --> `[indexing]`

The reason I'm suggesting `[index]` --> `[indexing]` is because it's impossible to get all users to split hairs between the meanings. Right now there are SQL-related index/indexing questions in both tags, and it would be a serious pain to separate them out and keep that maintained. There are also many questions about array indexes/indexing in both tags -- most of the time someone will ask a question with something like `[c#]` + `[index]`, which isn't very specific at all. Those should be separated out, which is a pretty big job no matter which way we go.